# All artisan commands throw PDOException

Tags: laravel

I have run into an extremely weird problem. At first I encountered it during migrations, but since then it is happening in all commands. Even `composer install` and `php artisan serve` tell me this:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.patent_examination_types' doesn'  
  t exist (SQL: select * from `patent_examination_types`)                                              


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.patent_examination_types' doesn'  
  t exist                                                                                              


  [PDOException]                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.patent_examination_types' doesn'  
  t exist
```

I've tried `composer dump-autoload`, which says `Generating autoload files` and then if I say `php artisan serve` I get the same result.

I'm quite puzzled!

Comment: do those tables exist in your database?

Comment: @MarcinC. Not as of now. But they're part of my application. It's only a single table in the error, by the way.

Comment: what artisan command you are running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your have deleted your `'patent_examination_types'` table from the database but this table is using in your code.

Check your code for `'patent_examination_types'` table, Maybe you have write this table in you some controller or model, Search this table throughout your code and comment it..
Hope it helps.